daul booting ubuntu desktop on samsung galaxy tab s9 fe
I want to dual boot android 14 and Ubuntu desktop os on my Galaxy Tab S9 fe (8gb ram 256gb ssd) do you think it would work/brick my device, if so than is there any fixes, thanks!

However, you can set up Ubuntu base image using Termux, and run an emulated Ubuntu environment, with GUI. This question is duplicate of: How can I set up and run Ubuntu Base image for Arm on my Android phone without rooting?.

Unless someone makes a custom bootloader and a custom Ubuntu image for your device, you can't install Ubuntu on just any Android tablet
